# Why can't ref to refresh button?

Tags: extjs, view, controller, refs

I'm creating an ExtJS 5.1.1 demo app. Try to give a `refs` for **refresh** button of **gridpanel**, so that I'll able to set a function for reload the data inside the grid.

I guess that I can't create correct `refs` for both **Grid** panel and **Refresh** button. Therefore click event is not working.

**MainView**:

```
Ext.define('MultiDB.view.DBMainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
    alias: 'widget.dbmainview',
    requires: [ ... ],
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
             items: [{
                xtype: 'dbmenupanel',
                region: 'west'
            }, {
                xtype: 'dbgridpanel',
                region: 'center'
            }, {
                xtype: 'dbformpanel',
                region: 'south'
            }]
        });
        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

**Grid Panel**:

```
Ext.define('MultiDB.view.DBGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'dbgridpanel',
    store: 'FolioStore',
    requires: [...],

    title: 'ORest DB List',
    padding: 1,
    itemId: 'gridPanel',
    dockedItems: [...],

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
            tools: [{
                type: 'refresh',
                itemId: 'refreshBtn',
                tooltip: 'Refresh the DB',
                //handler: function () {alert('Click: Refresh Btn');}
            }],

            columns: [...]
        });
        me.callParent();
    }
});
```

**Controller**:

```
Ext.define('MultiDB.controller.DBMainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['DBGridPanel'],

    refs: {
        formPanel: 'dbformpanel#formPanel',
        gridPanel: 'dbgridpanel#gridPanel',
        mainView: 'dbmainview#mainView',
        registrationBtn: 'splitbutton#registrationBtn',
        refreshBtn: 'dbmainview dbgridpanel#refreshBtn'
    },

    init: function (application) {
        this.control({
            "menuitem[opt]": {
                click: this.setFormPanel
            },
            "dbmainview dbgridpanel#refreshBtn": {
                viewready: this.doRefresh
            }
        });
    },

    setFormPanel: function (item) {...},

    doRefresh: function () {
        console.log('this is doInit!');
        this.getGridPanel().getStore().load();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ref to the gridpanel seems to be correct. But the syntax of your ref to the refreshBtn is incorrect. Let's start with taking apart some correct syntax:

> dbgridpanel#gridPanel

This says that the ref should resolve to a widget with xtype `dbgridpanel` and id `gridPanel`.

> dbgridpanel#refreshBtn

say that the ref should resolve to a widget with xtype `dbgridpanel` and id `refreshBtn`, which cannot be resolved, because said id is used for a `tool`, not a `dbgridpanel`.

The correct ref to your refresh tool would be

> dbgridpanel #refreshBtn

which tells the ref to resolve to a widget with id `refreshBtn` which is a child of another widget of xtype `dbgridpanel`, or in the long form (which I recommend to use for clarity)

> dbgridpanel#gridPanel tool#refreshBtn

which tells the ref to resolve to a widget with xtype `tool` and id `refreshBtn` which is a child of another widget with xtype `dbgridpanel` and id `gridPanel`.

Comment: That works wonderful... Thanks a lot @Alexandar. BTW I had to change `viewready: this.doRefresh` to `click: this.doRefresh`. Now when I checked Chrome Dev-Tool's **Network** tab, the new list is loading w/out any problem. =)